# AlamoFire Download in Background Session

Tags: ios, swift, network-programming, alamofire

I am using Alamofire within a new app (A Download Manager Sample based on Alamofire)
I need some clarifications about downloading files using the background session.
I need to override SessionDelegate to get it works?
Or just `backgroundCompletionHandler`?

Typically what are the steps to handle downloads in background using Alamofire?
And how can I handle the case where my app is relauch, with downloads in flux.

Comment: https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire, go to section **Downloading a File**, and Alamofire requests are asynchronous

Answer (score 34, accepted):

#### Update

Based on [this amazing tutorial](https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-part-2-background-download-863426842e21), I have put together an example project available on [GitHub](https://github.com/jozsef-vesza/swift-lessons/tree/master/Networking). It has an example for background session management.

According to Apple's [URL Loading System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW26):

> In both iOS and OS X, when the user relaunches your app, your app
>   should immediately create background configuration objects with the
>   same identifiers as any sessions that had outstanding tasks when your
>   app was last running, then create a session for each of those
>   configuration objects. These new sessions are similarly automatically
>   reassociated with ongoing background activity.

So apparently by using the appropriate background session configuration instances, your downloads will never be "in flux".

I have also found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359684/1832052) really helpful.

#### Original answer

From Alamofire's [GitHub page](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire#creating-a-manager-with-background-configuration):

> Applications can create managers for background and ephemeral
>   sessions, as well as new managers that customize the default session
>   configuration, such as for default headers (HTTPAdditionalHeaders) or
>   timeout interval (timeoutIntervalForRequest).

By default, top level methods use a shared `Manager` instance with default session configuration. You can however create a manager with background session configuration like so:

```
let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("com.example.app.background")
let manager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
```

You can then make requests using this `Manager` instance.

```
manager.startRequestsImmediately = true
let request = NSURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "your.url.here")!)
manager.request(request)
```

By looking at its implementation, it also has a property called `backgroundCompletionHandler`, so you can add a completion block:

```
manager.backgroundCompletionHandler = {
        // do something when the request has finished
    }
```

Comment: My destinationURL is nil if I fire a download request with the above URL. and the file downloaded doesnt get downloaded using above manager. @JózsefVesza

Answer (score 33):

**EDIT**

With Alamofire 5 this is no longer possible, see the release notes:

> Using a `URLSessionConfiguration` with a background identifier is not
>   possible any more. We're explicitly ensuring Alamofire isn't used with
>   background sessions, in order to prevent ongoing issues around support
>   and surprise on the part of the user.

**Old answer, still valid if you use Alamofire 4**

It's actually very easy with Alamofire:

1) your Alamofire.Manager should be configured with a background session identifier:

```
class NetworkManager {
    ...
    private lazy var backgroundManager: Alamofire.SessionManager = {
        let bundleIdentifier = ...
        return Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: bundleIdentifier + ".background"))
    }()
    ...
}
```

2) in the App Delegate implement `application(_:handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession:completionHandler:` and pass the completion handler to `Alamofire.SessionManager.backgroundCompletionHandler`.

In my case the app delegate method looks like

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    NetworkManager.default.backgroundCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}
```

and my network manager has a computed property like this to set the Manager property:

```
var backgroundCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)? {
    get {
        return backgroundManager.backgroundCompletionHandler
    }
    set {
        backgroundManager.backgroundCompletionHandler = newValue
    }
}
```

Comment: This won't work, see https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/commit/1d5411cdde887cb9c8d282239fa4a44d42bd5e9f

Answer (score 10):

I was searching for the solution quite long. Until read the article mentioned above. The issue for me was - I had to enable **External accessory communication**

[image]

Everything else was done as described above.
AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        BackendAPIManager.sharedInstance.backgroundCompletionHandler = completionHandler
    }
```

Singleton:

```
import Alamofire

class BackendAPIManager: NSObject {
    static let sharedInstance = BackendAPIManager()

    var alamoFireManager : Alamofire.SessionManager!

    var backgroundCompletionHandler: (() -> Void)? {
        get {
            return alamoFireManager?.backgroundCompletionHandler
        }
        set {
            alamoFireManager?.backgroundCompletionHandler = newValue
        }
    }

    fileprivate override init()
    {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "com.url.background")
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 200 // seconds
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 200
        self.alamoFireManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
    }
}
```

And the calls are done in the following way:

```
BackendAPIManager.sharedInstance.alamoFireManager.upload(multipartFormData: { (multipartFormData) in ...
```

Comment: Does your app not need to actually have functionality whereby it communicate with an external accessory in order for Apple to approve an app with this background mode ticked?

Comment: Why do you need to enable External accessory communication? This becomes an issue when submitting the app to the AppStore.

Comment: It's a really poor solution when you tell people to tick "magic boxes" without explaining why, or how it affects App Store acceptance.