# AFNetworking 3.0 continuing upload when app moves to background

Tags: ios, swift, afnetworking, afnetworking-3

My app initiates uploading content to a server while in the foreground. Since this process could take some time, the user could very well transition the app to the background.

I'm using AFHTTPSessionManager to submit the upload:

```
let sessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
sessionManager.requestSerializer.setValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-type")
sessionManager.POST(urlStr, parameters: params, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData) -> Void in
    formData.appendPartWithFileData(dataObject, name: "object", fileName: mimeType == "image/jpg" ? "pic.jpg" : "pic.mp4", mimeType: mimeType)
}, progress: { (progress) -> Void in
}, success: { (task, responseObject) -> Void in
    print(responseObject)
    success(responseObject: responseObject)
}, failure: { (task, error) -> Void in
    print(error)
    if let errorData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] as? NSData {
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(errorData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            failure(error: error, responseObject: json)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
    }
})
```

I need this process to continue while the app is in the background state until completion. There's an excellent SO answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21359684/2410991) which has gotten me on the right track, but I'm still in the dark in some places. I've tried using the "BackgroundSessionManager" class from the linked answer to change my upload call to this:

```
BackgroundSessionManager.sharedManager().POST(NetworkManager.kBaseURLString + "fulfill_request", parameters: params, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData) -> Void in
    formData.appendPartWithFileData(dataObject, name: "object", fileName: mimeType == "image/jpg" ? "pic.jpg" : "pic.mp4", mimeType: mimeType)
}, progress: nil, success: nil, failure: nil)?.resume()
```

And added this to my AppDelegate:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: () -> Void) {
    BackgroundSessionManager.sharedManager().savedCompletionHandler = completionHandler
}
```

But I'm getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on some background thread with little to no information. Am I even approaching this correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. You are building a multipart request, but then forcing the `Content-Type` header to be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`. But that's not a valid content header for multipart requests. I'd suggest removing that manual configuration of the request header (or tell us why you're doing that). AFNetworking will set the `Content-Type` for you.
2. Rather than bothering with background sessions at all, you might just want to request a little time to complete the request even after the user leaves the app.

   ```
   var backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid

   func uploadImageWithData(dataObject: NSData, mimeType: String, urlStr: String, params: [String: String]?, success: (responseObject: AnyObject?) -> (), failure: (error: NSError, responseObject: AnyObject) -> ()) {
       let app = UIApplication.sharedApplication()

       let endBackgroundTask = {
           if self.backgroundTask != UIBackgroundTaskInvalid {
               app.endBackgroundTask(self.backgroundTask)
               self.backgroundTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid
           }
       }

       backgroundTask = app.beginBackgroundTaskWithName("com.domain.app.imageupload") {
           // if you need to do any addition cleanup because request didn't finish in time, do that here

           // then end the background task (so iOS doesn't summarily terminate your app
           endBackgroundTask()
       }

       let sessionManager = AFHTTPSessionManager()
       sessionManager.POST(urlStr, parameters: params, constructingBodyWithBlock: { (formData) -> Void in
           formData.appendPartWithFileData(dataObject, name: "object", fileName: mimeType == "image/jpg" ? "pic.jpg" : "pic.mp4", mimeType: mimeType)
           }, progress: { (progress) -> Void in
           }, success: { (task, responseObject) -> Void in
               print(responseObject)
               success(responseObject: responseObject)
               endBackgroundTask()
           }, failure: { (task, error) -> Void in
               print(error)
               if let errorData = error.userInfo[AFNetworkingOperationFailingURLResponseDataErrorKey] as? NSData {
                   do {
                       let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(errorData, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
                       failure(error: error, responseObject: json)
                   } catch let error {
                       print(error)
                   }
               }
               endBackgroundTask()
       })
   }
   ```
3. I'd suggest adding an [exception breakpoint](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-breakpoint_navigator/articles/adding_an_exception_breakpoint.html) and see if that helps you track down the offending line.

   Frankly, if the exception is occurring asynchronously inside the `NSURLSession` internal processing, this might not help, but it's the first thing I try whenever trying to track down the source of an exception.
4. If you really feel like you must use background session (i.e. your upload task(s) are likely to take more than the three minutes that `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` permits), then be aware that background task must be upload or download tasks.

   But, I believe that the `POST` method will create a data task. In iOS 7, you aren't allowed to use data tasks with background sessions at all. In iOS 8, you can initiate a data task with a background task, but you have to respond to `didReceiveResponse` with `NSURLSessionResponseBecomeDownload`, e.g. in `configureDownloadFinished` of that `BackgroundSessionManager`, you can try adding:

   ```
   [self setDataTaskDidReceiveResponseBlock:^NSURLSessionResponseDisposition(NSURLSession *session, NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask, NSURLResponse *response) {
       return NSURLSessionResponseBecomeDownload;
   }];
   ```
5. Alternatively, if, again, you must use background session, then you might want manually build your `NSURLRequest` object and just submit it as an upload or download task rather than using `POST`. AFNetworking provides mechanisms to decouple the building of the request and the submitting of the request, so if you need to go down that road, let us know and we can show you how to do that.

Bottom line, `beginBackgroundTaskWithName` is going to be much easier way to request a little time to finish a request than using background `NSURLSession`. Only do the latter if you absolutely must (e.g. there's a good chance that you'll need more than three minutes to finish the request).

Comment: Thank you so much for being so thorough. I'll try some of the different things you suggest and post an update.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, where are you getting the 3 minute time limit for the simpler background task? Apple seems to be pretty vague about the actual time limit, but I'm seeing elsewhere that it can support up to 10 minutes.

Comment: It's not formally documented anywhere that I know of, though I have a vague recollection of it being referenced in one of the WWDC videos. It used to be 10 minutes, but is now 3 minutes, AFAIK. If you call [`backgroundTimeRemaining`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIApplication/backgroundTimeRemaining), it will tell you precisely how much time you have been given.

Comment: Thanks again. Ended up going with `beginBackgroundTaskWithName`. We might want to use background sessions in the future, but the simpler is working well.

Comment: @Rob What to do for Uploading task taking more than 3 minutes? I want to upload video to the server with parameters and using AFNetworking. used post, upload task & data task methods. but the system provides only 3 minutes for uploading.after that application terminate and uploading stop.

Comment: @BhargavB.Bajani - Then you're stuck doing background `URLSession` in which case using AlamoFire becomes much more awkward. It's like http://stackoverflow.com/a/42915383/1271826. Or see http://stackoverflow.com/a/26542755/1271826 (which is download, but goes over some of the issues with background sessions).

Comment: it's solved just create backgroundtask and terminate when uploading end.

Thanks for our reply