# API call and Download file while application in background

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

In my application functionality user can download folder and file from server.

### Application flow Steps

1. Download Folder button click
2. **FolderSize** =  API call "Get folder info" (this API return size of folder and list of file URL which is contain by folder)
3. **DeviceFreeMemorySize** = get Device free memory size

### Next step for download process

```
if DeviceFreeMemorySize > FolderSize {
    startDownloadFile()
} else {
    display local notification
}
```

Everything work fine if my application running in foreground.

While on **step 2** application moves in background by using home button. my API not work. and i will not get **FolderSize**

By using this code

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: backgroundIdentifier)
let manager: SessionManager = SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
manager.download(url) // Download file
```

Above code help me to download file while application in background

Bellow code for Get folder info API call

```
manager.request(url, method: .get, parameters: nil, encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON { (response:DataResponse<Any>) in

            print("Response: \(String(describing: response.result.value))")
            switch(response.result) {
            case .success(_):
                break

            case .failure(let error):
                print(error)

                break
            }
        }
```

But this code not work while application in background

**Que:- How my API work in background.?**

i have check below links:-

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540689/how-to-make-alamofire-download-progress-run-in-background-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540689/how-to-make-alamofire-download-progress-run-in-background-ios%20%20https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-part-2-background-download-863426842e21%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134652/alamofire-download-in-background-session)

[https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-part-2-background-download-863426842e21](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26540689/how-to-make-alamofire-download-progress-run-in-background-ios%20%20https://medium.com/swift-programming/learn-nsurlsession-using-swift-part-2-background-download-863426842e21%20%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134652/alamofire-download-in-background-session)

[AlamoFire Download in Background Session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30134652/alamofire-download-in-background-session)

Comment: Select Target -> Capabilities -> BackgroundMode -> check Background fetch

Comment: @Torongo is correct. Study background modes to know how to achieve this.

Comment: @Torongo Still it not works