# Handling of Alamofire requests as iOS app is terminating

Tags: ios, alamofire, application-lifecycle

AppDelegate.applicationWillTerminate is called when the application is about to terminate.  In this function, I am issuing a network request via Alamofire, to notify the server that the app is terminating. Alamofire's response handler is never invoked. It looks to me like the termination completes before the completion handler is invoked.

Alamofire's completion handlers appear to run on the main thread. I found documentation saying that the app is responsible for draining the main queue: "Although you do not need to create the main dispatch queue, you do need to make sure your application drains it appropriately. For more information on how this queue is managed, see Performing Tasks on the Main Thread." (From https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/OperationQueues/OperationQueues.html) And this is where I am stuck.

How do I drain the main thread? I need to ensure that this last Alamofire request runs before the main thread exits.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into the first link. I get why Alamofire handles the response in a closure, that's how it should be done. It seems odd to me that iOS is somehow (how?) shutting down connectivity before applicationWillTerminate returns. Is that actually what's happening? The same request runs fine in other contexts.

Answer (score 3):

Don't worry about “draining” the main thread. The problem is more simple than that. It's just a question of how to do something when your app is leaves the “foreground”/“active” state.

When a user leaves your app to go do something else, it is generally not terminated. It enters a “suspended” state where it remains in memory but does not execute any code. So when the app is suspended, it cannot process your request (but the app isn't yet terminated, either).

There are two approaches to solve this problem.

1. You could just request a little time to finish your request (see [Extending Your App's Background Execution Time](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/app_and_environment/scenes/preparing_your_ui_to_run_in_the_background/extending_your_app_s_background_execution_time/)). By doing this, your app is not suspended, but temporarily enters a "background" state, where execution can continue for a short period of time.

   The advantage of this approach is that it is fairly simple process. Just get background task id before starting the request and you tell it that the background task is done in the Alamofire completion handler.

   The disadvantage of this approach is that you only have 30 seconds (previously 3 minutes) for the request to be processed. If you have a good connection, this is generally adequate. But if you don't have a good network connection in that period, the request might never get sent.
2. The second approach is a little more complicated: You could make your request using a background `URLSession`. In this scenario, you are effectively telling iOS to take over the handling of this request, and the OS will continue to do so, even if your app is suspends (or later terminated during its natural lifecycle).

   But this is much more complicated than the first approach I outlined, and you lose much of the ease and elegance of Alamofire in the process. You can contort yourself to do it (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/26542755/1271826 for an example), but it is far from the obvious and intuitive interface that you're used to with Alamofire. For example, you cannot use the simple `response`/`responseJSON` completion handlers. You can only download/upload tasks (no data tasks). You have to write code to handle the OS restarting your app to tell you that the network request was sent (even if you're not doing anything meaningful with this response). Etc.

   But the advantage of this more complicated approach is that it is more robust. There's no 3 minute limit to this process. The OS will still take care of sending the request on your behalf whenever connectivity is reestablished. Your app may may even be terminated by that point in time, and the OS will still send the request on your behalf.

Note, neither of these approaches can handle a "force-quit" (e.g. the user double taps on the home button and swipes up to terminate the app). It just handles the normal graceful leaving of the app to go do something else.

Comment: you said that neither of these solutions work with “force-quit”. Is there no way to guarantee an API when force quitting?

Comment: No, there isn't.